# Unable to import todoist.api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, todoist

Trying to access the `todoist` api, and I copied some code from the api documentation. However, on my system I get an error stating:

> ```
> Unable to import 'todoist.api'pylint(import-error).
> ```

I installed it with:

```
pip install todoist-python
```

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v7/?shell#summary-of-contents)

```
from todoist.api import TodoistAPI
```

I get my error on the very first line. How do I not get this?

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right, so it's probably related to the way your installation is set.

Be sure you are using the same python you used to install the library. Check if the library is installed (`pip list`) and check if you're using the right Python when running the code. It's possible that the library was installed in one version and you're using the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by following the GitHub instructions, but the name of the module to install using pip is `todoist`.